# HTML / CSS Elements to do not fit / align on page as desired

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to fill the page with a background image using CSS/HTML however it does not seem to fill the page as I would like. How might this be avoided?

I've done the best I can seem to do using the source below - but I'm not sure exactly what can be done to fix it.

### Three Main Issues:

Background does not fill completely

Green text on the left side does not align w the green box behind it.

The menu items at the top of the screen do not align with the (woodgrain) graphics behind it.

### Screenshot:

[image]

### Source:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen" >
</style>
<title>Print</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

</head>


<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:15px; LEFT:160px;  width="297" height="182" SRC="header-logo.png">
<div style=" background: url(background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1280px; height:1024px;">

       <a href="index.html" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="position:absolute; left:70px; top:245px; width:62px; height:19px;  font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #A0CC54;
  color : rgb(160, 204, 84);" title="Edible Treasures - Home">Home</div></a>
       >


  <a href="about.html" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style=" position:absolute; left:196px; top:243px; width:65px; height:19px;  font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="Edible Treasures - About">About</div></a>

   <a href="recipes.html" style="cursor:hand">
        <div style="position:absolute; left:314px; top:244px; width:78px; height:23px;  font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="Edible Treasures - Recipes">Recipes
        </div></a

  ><a href="blogs.html" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 467px; top: 243px; width: 56px; height: 24px;  font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="Edible Treasures - Blogs">Blogs
        </div></a>







       <a href="contact.html" style="cursor:hand">
        <div style=" position:absolute; left:571px; top:244px; width:82px; height:18px; font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="Edible Treasures - Contact">Contact 
        </div></a>



        <div style="background-image:url(welcome.png); position:absolute; left:476px; top:357px; width:738px; height:52px;" title="Edible Treasures - Welcome">
  </div
    ><div style=" position:absolute; left:476px; top:458px; width:736px; height:385px; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; 
  font-family : Baskerville;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-style : italic;
  font-size : 18px;
  color : #4C3D38;
  color : rgb(76, 61, 56);">We are very fortunate to live in a time when at any time of day or night we can easily walk or drive to the store and have a choice
      of different make available on our hands.
      With this luxury why would you spend your time growing your own food? I have a good simple answer to that: We are human. As humans, this is what we do. We grow food. This is what we have for thousands of years. It was not until the last hundred or so years that we put the responsibility of making food in the hands of others.<BR>
Who are the people responsible for growing and handling our food? <BR>
And what they are doing to our food? How are they treated? What they are spraying it? Is that good for you? <BR>
Is that good for the earth? Who really knows? They are professionals with <BR>
business interests more in mind than our health. What we do know that if we go to supermarket food is there year-round. <BR>
I am no scientist nor I studied this <BR>
extensively, but mind tells me it can not be good for us or for the land because it does not seem natural or sustainable.<BR>
</B></I></FONT>
    </div>
  <div style="  background : #A0CC54;
  background : rgba(160, 204, 84, 1);
position:absolute; left:82px; top:628px; width:301px; height:213px; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-family : Baskerville;
  font-size : 18px;
  color : #4C3D38;
  color : rgb(76, 61, 56); ">Some questions to get you thinking the next time you're in the grocery store buying food:<BR>
</FONT><FONT  COLOR=#000000> <BR>
</FONT><FONT  COLOR=#4C3C37>Who grow up?<BR>
How is it treated?<BR>
How is the worker who took it considered?<BR>
Do these people have my best interests in mind, or are they just trying to make a higher profit?</FONT>
    </div>


     <a href="index.html" style="cursor:hand">
        <div style=" position:absolute; left:740px; top:995px; width:48px; height:14px; font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="">Home
    </div></a>

   <a href="about.html" style="cursor:hand">  
  <div style=" position:absolute; left:843px; top:994px; width:49px; height:14px;  font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="">About    </div></a>


   <a href="Recipes.html" style="cursor:hand">
   <div style="position:absolute; left:941px; top:994px; width:65px; height:17px; font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="">Recipes
   </div></a>


    <a href="blogs.html" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="position:absolute; left:1061px; top:994px; width:45px; height:18px;  font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);" title="">Blogs
    </div></a>
     <a href="contact.html" style="cursor:hand">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:1153px; top:993px; width:64px; height:15px; font-family : Helvetica;
  font-size : 25px;
  color : #C49A6C;
  color : rgb(196, 154, 108);"  title="">Contact
    </div>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: clarify your two issues: 1. what is the result you want? a scroll bar on the green box so the text remains inside? / 2. What is the result you want? the text ontop of the wooden grain vertically aligned?

Comment: Why is the entire site using a single background image?  Is there a reason why you haven't broken up the image and placed the pieces in their corresponding <div>s?

Comment: Please don't tell me the whole thing is a background image.. is it?

Comment: The whole thing isn't a background image... but I do have a large background image which I would like to use (background.png)

Comment: If there is better way to implement the background (or anything else on the page) PLEASE do tell!! :)

Comment: Should I slice them into a header image and a background image?

Comment: This is just a side note... but I've started a fiddle for you to show you how to separate out your css.  it will be much easier for you to troubleshoot if you move all your css to an external file.  This might give you some hints:  http://jsfiddle.net/p1xelarchitect/d4GYm/

Comment: I REALLY appreciate it... I'm VERY new - so I need all the help I can get (even though this is a relatively simple site)

Comment: In terms of your green box problem.. you have set the exact width and height... and set its position to absolute.  This means that no matter how long the content inside the box, the size will not ever change.  I recommend wrapping the content in a <p>content here</p> tag.  If you want to keep the box that exact size, you have two options:

1. allow the content to scroll
2. make the font smaller

which do you want?

Comment: Scrolling sounds like a much better option

Comment: Also - will I need to use something such as: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> 

to specify the location of my external style sheet?

Comment: Regarding your background image - YES absolutely slice it up.  only include the pieces that you need.  In other words, you don't need to waste valuable bandwidth downloading a .jpg with tons of white space.

Comment: yes. put <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> in the <head></head> section of your html.

Comment: you can learn how to set your overflow properties for your green box, here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Question... take a look at the image I'm using as the background - it doesn't seem like there's a way to slice the background into a header and background since there are almost no straight lines in it - any suggestions? (I feel like if I slice a header image It's going to cut off some of the woodgrain - or the dots/leaves - know what I mean?) Is it really that bad to have one solid image as the background?

Comment: It all depends on how important this site is to you.  Is the purpose to just get something posted asap? is quality important?  and by quality I mean - how does it scale and behave on various sizes of monitors? from small 13" laptop to large 27" widescreen desktop monitor. how large is the file size and how long will it take to download?  how long is the delay between downloading the HTML content and the background image.  it might take 3 or 4 seconds in some cases before the image is loaded which isn't a great first impression...

Comment: My preference is to NEVER use a single giant background image unless you *have* to.  in those cases, I would always preload it into the DOM so the content and background image appear at exactly the same time.  (javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the main question:

1 - Add your main background to the `body`, not a div. You don't really need to worry about the images filesize, just make sure that you compress the jpeg file and it will be TINY.

CSS

```
body { 
    background: url(background.png) no-repeat top;
}
```

2 -  Remove the height from your sidebar to get that green box resizing with your content.

I would also use a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) that removes default browser styles and leaves you with a clean slate.

Now, to improve what you have ...

Ideally you should separate your CSS, here is a basic version of your page that I have simplified.  Create this as a new file and point the bodies background to your jpeg :)

Adjust the `nav`s padding to fit correctly with the background.

HTML / CSS

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

  <title>Print</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

  <style type="text/css">

  /* CSS Reset */

  html {  overflow-x: scroll;  }

  html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          font-size: 100%;
          vertical-align: baseline;
          background: transparent;
          font-family: Helvetica;
  } 
  /* end CSS Reset */



  body { 
    background: url(background.png) no-repeat top;
 }

  nav { 
      padding: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
  nav a { 
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px; }

  #sidebar { 
     float: left; 
     width: 200px; 
     height: 100%; 
     padding: 10px; 
     background : rgba(160, 204, 84, 1); 
  }

  #main-content { 
     float: left; 
     width: 500px; 
     padding: 10px;  
   }

  #main-content p {
      padding: 0 0 10px;
  }

  footer { 
      clear: left; 
      margin: 0 auto; 
      width: 440px; 
  }
  </style>

  </head>


  <body>

  <div id="wrap">

    <nav>

      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Recipes</a>
      <a href="#">Blogs</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>

    </nav>

    <div id="sidebar">
     Some questions to get you thinking the next time ...
    </div>

    <div id="main-content"><p>
    We are very fortunate to live in a time when at any time of day or night we can easily walk or drive to the store and have a choice
          of different make available on our hands.</p>
          <p>
          With this luxury why would you spend your time growing your own food? I have a good simple answer to that: We are human. As humans, this is what we do. We grow food. This is what we have for thousands of years. It was not until the last hundred or so years that we put the responsibility of making food in the hands of others.</p>
    <p>Who are the people responsible for growing and handling our food? 
    And what they are doing to our food? How are they treated? What they are spraying it? Is that good for you? </p>
    <p>
    Is that good for the earth? Who really knows? They are professionals with <br>
    business interests more in mind than our health. What we do know that if we go to supermarket food is there year-round. </p>
    <p>
    I am no scientist nor I studied this 
    extensively, but mind tells me it can not be good for us or for the land because it does not seem natural or sustainable.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="site-footer">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Recipes</a>
      <a href="#">Blogs</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </footer>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For "Green text on the left side does not align w the green box behind it." in the code where you mentioned the green box code just increase height of green box "height: 250px;" and add "padding:10px;"

Answer (score 0):

For the Green box on the left to cover all the text with de green background you must apply this:

```
height:auto; 
overflow: hidden;
```